# How can I transfer eth from an account wallet to a smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm creating a smart contract that allows people to pay for a monthly subscription

I got stacked in this :

how to transfer plan.amount from the user wallet to the smart contract?

```
 function subscribe(uint planId) external {
        Plan storage plan = plans[planId]; // plan is a struct 
        require(plan.merchant != address(0), 'address not valid');
        
        // I tried this and it didn't work
        bool sent = payable(address(this)).send(plan.amount);
            require(sent, "tx failed");
     
        emit PaymentSent(
          msg.sender, 
          plan.merchant,
          plan.amount, // the monthly amount for Subscription
          planId, 
          block.timestamp
        );
    
    
        subscriptions[msg.sender][planId] = Subscription(
          msg.sender,
          block.timestamp, 
          block.timestamp + 4 weeks // next payement
        );
        emit SubscriptionCreated(msg.sender, planId, block.timestamp);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have no control over the wallets that send tx to you contract

if pay should be in Ether:

- first you should have a `payable` function to be able to receive ether
- and then wallet should send ether with his tx

transferring any asset from wallet required wallet private key for signing the tx and you don't have it inside your contract

Answer (score 0):

In order to send or receive Ether, you must declare a function with the keyword `payable` . By applying the following changes:

```
function subscribe(uint planId, address payable _to) public payable {
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId]; // plan is a struct 
    require(plan.merchant != address(0), 'address not valid');
    
    // Send returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
    // This function is not recommended for sending Ether.
    bool sent = _to.send(msg.value);
    require(sent, "tx failed");

    emit PaymentSent(
      msg.sender, 
      plan.merchant,
      plan.amount, // the monthly amount for Subscription
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );


    subscriptions[msg.sender][planId] = Subscription(
      msg.sender,
      block.timestamp, 
      block.timestamp + 4 weeks // next payement
    );
    emit SubscriptionCreated(msg.sender, planId, block.timestamp);
  } 
}
```

It should now work.

Also, consider using `call` instead of 'send' as it is considered to be the recommended method for sending Ether:

```
function subscribe(uint planId, address payable _to) public payable {
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId]; // plan is a struct 
    require(plan.merchant != address(0), 'address not valid');
    
    // Call returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
    // This is the current recommended method to use.
    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(sent, "tx failed");

    emit PaymentSent(
      msg.sender, 
      plan.merchant,
      plan.amount, // the monthly amount for Subscription
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );


    subscriptions[msg.sender][planId] = Subscription(
      msg.sender,
      block.timestamp, 
      block.timestamp + 4 weeks // next payement
    );
    emit SubscriptionCreated(msg.sender, planId, block.timestamp);
  } 
}
```